# Quotient topology on $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Suppose $f : R \rightarrow S^1$, where $t \mapsto e^{2\pi *it}$. Consider R with the finite complement topology and consider the quotient topology on $S^1$. I have asked a question related to this before asking what is the quotient topology and I realised it is the trivial topology, however I don't know how can I prove it rigorously that it is the trivial topology?

$U \neq S^1$ open then we know that $f^{-1}(U)$ will have infinitely many points, so $R - f^{-1}(U)$ has infinite complement, but this can't happen by definition of quotient topology so we must have $f^{-1}(U) = \emptyset$

Answer (score 1):

Take some open $U\subset S^1$, and show that if $U\neq S^1$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ has infinite complement, so $U=\emptyset$.

Comment: I couldn't that part if $U \neq S^1$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ has infinite complement.

Comment: @Illustionist If $x\notin U$, what is $f^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: why does it have infinite complement can you please explain more....

Comment: Never mind I understand the reason this works is the following please correct me if I am wrong we have if we have $U \neq S^1$ open then we know that $f^{-1}(U)$ will have infinitely many points, so $R - f^{-1}(U)$ has infinite complement, but this can't happen by definition of quotient topology so we must have $f^{-1}(U) = \emptyset$

Comment: @Illustionist I don't understand your reasoning.  Again, consider some $x\notin U$.  How many points are there in $f^{-1}(x)$?  This is contained in the complement of $f^{-1}(U)$, and should give you your answer.